# Getting repetitive iterations while solving sinon, unable to do unit testing in nodejs

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to do unit testing in Nodejs using sinon.

And I have installed the following libraries -

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPjUU.png) npm i mocha

[2] npm i chai

[3] npm i sinon

And here is my code -

**unitTest-app.js**

```
 var sinon = require('sinon');


it('calls the original function', function(){

   var callback = sinon.fake();
   var proxy = once(callback);


   proxy();

   assert(callback.called);

   });



it('calls the original function only once', function () {
   var callback = sinon.fake();
   var proxy = once(callback);

    proxy();
    proxy();

     assert(callback.calledOnce);
     // ...or:
    // assert.equals(callback.callCount, 1);
   });
```

**unitTest.js**

```js
function once(fn) {
  var returnValue,
    called = false;
  return function() {
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      returnValue = fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    return returnValue;
  };
}
```

Unable to run the unit tests.

when running the command  -

```
npm run test
```

Getting error -

[image]

Comment: How is `npm run test` line in your `package.json`?

Comment: "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test"
  }   --> isn't this ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are npm scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha",
  "test:coverage": "nyc npm t"
},
```

Then, you can use the `npm test` command to run your test. Besides, you should put your test file into the correct directory. See https://mochajs.org/#the-test-directory

`once.js`:

```js
function once(fn) {
  var returnValue,
    called = false;
  return function() {
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      returnValue = fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    return returnValue;
  };
}

module.exports = { once };
```

`once.test.js`:

```js
var sinon = require('sinon');
var assert = require('assert');
var { once } = require('./once');

it('calls the original function', function() {
  var callback = sinon.fake();
  var proxy = once(callback);
  proxy();
  assert(callback.called);
});

it('calls the original function only once', function() {
  var callback = sinon.fake();
  var proxy = once(callback);
  proxy();
  proxy();
  assert(callback.calledOnce);
});
```

unit test result:

```
  ✓ calls the original function
  ✓ calls the original function only once

  2 passing (6ms)
```